# Kinds of PCB Boards

Tags: pcb, board

I'm new to the world of etching PCBs. I etched my first board yesterday, and though it was a success I didn't like the PCB look.  I saw this picture (attached) and I like the material of this boards and would like to know what it is.

example1:
[image]

example2:
[image]

Please give me links that talk about PCB boards types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's single sided FR4, the most common material in use for PCBs nowadays. You can buy this from any good electronics vendor ([example](http://uk.farnell.com/kelan/149054/pcb-plain-s-s-100x160mm/dp/149054) from [Farnell](http://uk.farnell.com/jsp/search/browse.jsp?N=203294&No=0&getResults=true&appliedparametrics=true&locale=en_UK&divisionLocale=en_UK&catalogId=&prevNValues=203294&filtersHidden=false&appliedHidden=false&originalQueryURL=/jsp/search/browse.jsp?N=203294&No=0&getResults=true&appliedparametrics=true&locale=en_UK&divisionLocale=en_UK&catalogId=&prevNValues=203294))
For etching purposes you can buy it precoated with [UV photoresist](http://uk.farnell.com/kelan/141300/pcb-photo-resist-s-s-100x160mm/dp/141300), for use with a mask and UV light box.
The [Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printed_circuit_board) will tell you about all the different types.

Comment: Can i use it with the Toner transfer method ?

Comment: Yes, you can use the plain FR4 with toner transfer. [Here](http://fullnet.com/~tomg/gooteepc.htm) is a link that might be of some use.

Comment: Note that FR4 requires special cutting equipment - not like the cheap Paper Epoxy boards.  You will need Tungsten Carbide drill bits, or you will find them blunting almost instantly.  Also, cutting the board itself is much harder and you really require a board guillotine, or a Tungsten Carbide router.  Also, the dust is much more hazardous than paper-epoxy as it contains glass.

Answer (score 0):

I use this FPC 16 paper composite material (about half-way down the page) for my home-made boards:

http://www.megauk.com/pcb_laminates.php

It's much easier to cut and drill than FR4, and is somewhat cheaper. It has the disadvantage of not being translucent, like FR4.

It only seems to be available with resist, so it isn't suitable for toner transfer. It might be possible to buy it without resist, but it would probably require a large order.

Comment: Are those the white PCBs you've shown us [pictures](http://webspace.webring.com/people/jl/leon_heller/pcb.html) of?

Comment: Yes. I often get asked about my white PCBs.